# Best Practice in CSRF Token Management for AJAX in Laravel 9+

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, laravel

In the context of Laravel 9+, AJAX requests require CSRF token exposure for necessary security measures. However, different approaches for token placement can affect code elegance and organization. Two primary methods seem to be:

**Approach 1: Direct CSRF Token Insertion via Blade Syntax**

In this method, the CSRF token is directly embedded into the JavaScript via Blade syntax. (duplicating the same code in many places)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajaxSetup({
        headers: {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': "{{ csrf_token() }}"
        }
    });
});
```

Although this approach keeps the token out of the HTML body, it necessitates Blade syntax in JavaScript files, complicating the separation of concerns.

**Approach 2: CSRF Token Extraction from Meta Tag**

This method involves placing the CSRF token in an HTML meta tag, then extracting it for use in AJAX setup.

`<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">`

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajaxSetup({
        headers: {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
        }
    });
});
```

Here, even though the token is exposed in HTML (it is exposed either-way), it simplifies JavaScript file management, re-use and easier to keep code/concerns separated.

Considering the above, I'm guessing Approach 2 is better for its elegance and separation of concerns? Or are there alternative best practices in Laravel for managing CSRF token placement with AJAX requests that offer better balance of security and code organization? I look forward to your insights.

PS I looked at e.g. https://cheatsheetseries.owasp.org/cheatsheets/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet.html but some of that goes over my head

Comment: #2 as that's how Laravel recommends doing it in their docs: https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/csrf#csrf-x-csrf-token

Comment: I think that there is no "better" way. Both techniques are equally present in programming. Suggestion for method 2, you have Blade shortcode for token `@csrf`

Comment: CSRF tokens mean that it is telling the server that it only had generated the form and gave it to the client and it isn't coming from any 3rd party. Either of the approach you can use, it doesn't matter as long as it is being sent.

Comment: I would not advise in using  `ajaxSetup` because after you've done that it makes it impossible to undo and that will also affect ajax requests to 3rd parties. It's easy to put the `ajaxSetup` code in a .blade template and then forget. Then you'd just be sending a valid CSRF token to any 3rd party you may make a request to. Personally I do `window.csrfToken = {{ csrf_token() }}` and then access it via `window.csrfToken` whenever I need it. That means I have to code it in for every request that needs it

Comment: Thanks @apokryfos - that is an interesting and valid observation, though i think 'impossible' might be a strong word, though changing it down the line could certainly involve a lot of refactoring, alternatively, I suppose if we ever do need to ajax to 3rd party one could manage that by exception with e.g. `headers: { 'X-CSRF-TOKEN': null ... in that call - though admitly more error prone if and when multiple code authors on the project etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Here, even though the token is exposed in HTML (it is exposed either-way)

The token is only exposed to the user who you want to have it (so they can send it back to you).

It isn't exposed to any attacker. (Unless they've compromised communication between the server and the browser in a way that means they already have more access than a successful CSRF attack would give them.)

Take the straightforward option.